# google datastore aggregate query

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have been reading a lot on ways to do aggregate queries on the datastore (thru stackoverflow and elsewhere). The preponderance of answers is that it cannot be done in a pleasant way. But then those answers are dated, and the same people tend to also claim that you cannot do things such as `order by` on the datastore.

As it exists today, you actually can specify `ORDER BY` on the [datastore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries#Sort_Orders). So I am wondering if aggregation is also possible.

Consider the scenario where I have five candidates Alpha, Brave, Charie, Delta and Echo; and 10,000 voters. I want to retrieve the candidates and the number of votes each received in order. How would I do that on the datastore? I am using java.

Also, as an aside, if the answer is still no and fanning-in is my best option: is fan-in thread safe? By fanning-in I mean keeping an explicit counter that counts the vote each candidate receives (in a separate `table`). Could I experience a race condition or some other faults in the data when multiple users are voting concurrently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by aggregating you mean having the datastore compute the total # of votes for you, then no, the datastore won't do that.

The best way to do what you're describing is:

- Create a set of sharded counters per candidate (google search for app engine sharded counters).
- When someone votes, update the sharded counter for the given delegate.
- When you want to read the votes, query for your delegates, then for each delegate, query for the sharded counters and sum them up.
- Memcache for better performance, the GAE sharding counters example available in the docs shows this pretty well.

Comment: Thanks for the thought on sharded counters. +1. But the problem is if I use sharding, I won't be able to call `ORDER BY` votes on my candidates.

Comment: If you aren't worried about performance, you can keep the vote count in the actual Candidate entity, and then you can do ORDER_BY.  Otherwise, you can't.  But it's trivial to sort yourself after you've pullled the counts.

Answer (score 0):

Its recently launched and available for use now: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/aggregation-queries.

There are various client libraries also which support this particular feature.